# A matrix is producing 2 different answers

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

One quick question that I stumbled across when I started to learn python. I find this output peculiar. I wanted to make a 2D calculator but my 'matrixcreator' function apparently produces a different matrix than I think it is. Why isn't the vector from 'matrixmultiplicator' the same? Thanks

```
def matrixmultiplicator(matrix, vector1, vector2,):
    for x in range(len(vector1)):
        for y in range(len(vector2)):
           matrix[0][0]=vector1[x]*vector2[y]
    return matrix

def matrixcreator(x,y):
   matrix=[]
   list=[]
   #create first dimension
   for a in range(x):
       matrix.insert(a,0)
   #Create the second dimension
   for b in range(y):
       list.append(0)
       for a in range(x):
           matrix[a]=list
   return matrix

if __name__ == '__main__':
   a=[2,4]
   b=[2,4]
   matrix=[[0,0],[0,0]]
   print(matrix)
   print(matrixmultiplicator(matrix,a,b))
   matrix=matrixcreator(2,2)
   print(matrix)
   print(matrixmultiplicator(matrix,a,b))
```

The output in pycharm (which I use) is:

[[0, 0], [0, 0]]

[[16, 0], [0, 0]]

[[0, 0], [0, 0]]

[[16, 0], [16, 0]]

Comment: can you fix indenting on matrixcreator so we can see what it does? As it shows now, you would get an error.

Comment: " Why isn't the vector from 'matrixmultiplicator' the same? " The same as what? What do you expect the result to be?

Comment: I suggest that you learn how to debug your code. You can add `print()` statements or use the debugger from an IDE, such as PyCharm. Either way, you need to view the values of the variables in your program and figure out where they are different than what you expect. Then you need to figure out **why** they are different from what you expect.

Comment: You can see the output in the bottom. it's all there. But they solved it farther down. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you should create your matrix. You need a new list for each index, and you were doing some unnecessary steps before.

```
def matrixcreator(x,y):
   matrix=[]
   #create first dimension
   for a in range(x):
       list=[]
       for b in range(y):
           list.append(0)
       matrix.insert(a,list)
   return matrix
```

I think your multiplication routine is wrong, too, but I'm not sure. Why use a matrix for the result if you only set one coordinate?

Comment: That solved the problem! I was making a 3D calculator as practice but got these fundamental steps wrong so I had to make it simpler to see where the problem was. The purpose is to make up custom matrices and then multiply them.

Answer (score 1):

In `matrix=[[0,0],[0,0]]` you use two different lists to represent the second dimension. In the matrix creator however, you refer to the same list object that you assigned using `list=[]`.

EDIT: This can be seen in

```
for a in range(x):
   matrix[a]=list
```

where the same list object is assigned to multiple positions in the matrix.

Besides that, I'm not quite sure what you intend to do with your code. The looping feels off. First you insert x zeros into the `matrix`. Subsequently you add zeroes to the list and for each iteration of that step, you overwrite each index of the matrix with the same list object.

EDIT 2: Assuming that you want to create a matrix with x rows and y columns, you could simplify the code to:

```
def matrixcreator(x,y):
    return [[0] * y for _ in range(x)]
```

which creates a list comprehension consisting of x DIFFERENT lists filled with y zeros.

Comment: True that! Think that's the problem, that it's referring to the same list with same memory adress or something like that. Will have to find a way to allocate two different list objects. Thanks man.